# Local tlog backup and Azure full

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, backups

I am attempting to create a maintenance plan for a local transaction log backup.

The location of the full backup is listed as an Azure address ({C58FA3E7-ABB7-........}) so the maintenance plan thinks there is no full backup.

Is it possible to still create the local transaction log backup without access to Azure?

Right now the only way I can get the tlog backups to not fail is if I create a new full backup manually on the local disk.

Comment: I don't think you meant to tag this as azure-sql-database?  backups are handled by the system in the PaaS model.

Comment: Thank you for fixing the tags.  I am dealing with a client that doesn't understand full recovery mode.  I need to setup local tlog backups for SQL Server but Azure full.  Do I have to setup tlog backups in Azure as well or do I have the option of tlog local using maintenance plans?

Comment: On Azure SQL Database you have automated backups performed by Azure SQL Database with a retention of 35 days (you cannot control their execution), you also have long-term backups that you have control over their execution, and you can schedule exports of the database as bacpac.

Comment: You can't control the recovery model in SQL Azure.  It is always 'full'.  The service automatically takes short-term backups for you and you can configure long-term retention as Alberto mentions but you don't do that by directly taking tlog backups.  It is all done under the covers for you in PaaS.  You just have an interface to pick a point in time from which you want to restore a copy of the db.

Comment: So does that mean I leave the database in Simple recovery mode?